# How to generate screenshots of Unfolding maps as files/bytearrays?

Tags: java, maps

I have a Java web app and it to display dynamically generated maps (in form of images) with some markers. I have found [Unfolding maps lib](http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/) that looks interesting and I want to use it. However, all [examples](https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/tree/master/examples)  of this library contain only desktop apps. I have no idea how to transform UnfoldingMap object into png file without displaying it on a screen (i am building web, not desktop app).

If you know better libraries for this purpose, you can also let me know.

I have tried following code inside SatelliteProviderMapApp example, however it throws Nullpointer

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SatelliteProviderMapApp map = new SatelliteProviderMapApp();
        PApplet.runSketch(new String[] { SatelliteProviderMapApp.class.getName() }, map);
        LargeMapImageUtils util = new LargeMapImageUtils(map, map.map);
        PImage pImage = util.makeSnapshot();
        pImage.save("aa.png");
    }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.LargeMapImageUtils.makeSnapshot(LargeMapImageUtils.java:169)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.examples.provider.SatelliteProviderMapApp.main(SatelliteProviderMapApp.java:47)
Unfolding Map v0.9.93
Using OpenGLMapDisplay with processing.opengl.PGraphics2D
translate() with x, y, and z coordinates can only be used with a renderer that supports 3D, such as P3D. Use a version without a z-coordinate instead.
```